# Move the files from a folder and its subfolder to the same destination folder

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script to move files of type `.txt` to a particular folder. It looks for the files in work folder and move it to completed folder.

For example, if there is a `.txt` file in folder `/tmp/swan/test/work` and also in folder `/tmp/swan/test11/work`, the files should move to `/tmp/swan/test/completed` and `/tmp/swan/test11/completed` respectively.

Also, if there is a `.txt` file in a sub-folder like `/tmp/swan/test11/work/APX` that should also move to `/tmp/swan/test11/completed`.

Below is my script. Right now script is moving the files from the work folder rightly, but it is not moving the files from the sub-folder, i.e from work/completed folder to the respective done folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_DIR=/tmp/swan

cd $MY_DIR
find . -path "*work*"  -iname "*.txt" -type f -execdir mv '{}' ../completed \;
```

Comment: Do  subfolders already exist?

Answer (score 0):

assumming

- not nested work dir
- no funny name

try

```
MY_DIR=/tmp/swan

cd $MY_DIR

for w in */work 
do 
  find $w -path "*work*"  -iname "*.txt" -type f -execdir mv '{}' $MY_DIR/$w/completed \;
done
```

this would transfer your file to a fouth level dir named completed, having same third name as work.

if work dir are unnest but at an arbitrary level

```
MY_DIR=/tmp/swan

cd $MY_DIR

find $MY_DIR -type d -name \*work\* -print | while read w 
do 
  find $w -path "*work*"  -iname "*.txt" -type f -execdir mv '{}' $MY_DIR/$w/completed \;
done
```